# PagSeguro - Problema ao consultar Brand

Tags: jquery, python, django

Olá, estou tentando utilizar o checkout transparente do pagseguro. Já integrei a geração de sessão, porém ao consultar a bandeira do cartão, a função `success` nunca é chamada, apenas `error` e `complete`. Porém, a resposta nunca mostra qual o erro, apenas mostra que ele existe, com `response.error = true`.

Estou Utilizando o código do exemplo da documentação, então não consigo entender qual o erro nesse caso. Segue o código da função abaixo:

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
  cardBin: 4111111,
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  complete: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
});
```

Estou desenvolvendo o Back-End em django, e usando JQuery 3.5.1. Há algum erro em meu código? Grato.

Comment: já tentou olhar a documentação da API ou o suporte? acho q eles conseguem ajudar rapidamente, pq o seu código parece ok, talvez faltem parametros

Comment: Infelizmente sim, este é o exemplo da própria documentação, estou me baseando completamente neles, porém não estou obtendo sucesso. Tentei enviar uma mensagem diretamente. Obrigado